# Typescript satisfies turns boolean type to literal. Is this normal?

Tags: typescript

While other types are same, type 'boolean' become literal 'false' after satisfies "TypesSamples"

```
interface TypesSamples {
  str: string;
  int: number;
  arr: Array<any>;
  bool: boolean;
}

const types = {
  str: "a",
  int: 0,
  arr: [1],
  bool: false,
} satisfies TypesSamples; // satisfies here

types.str = "abc";
types.int = 1000;
types.arr = [2, 3];
types.bool = true; // Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'false'.
```

Is this an expected behaviour or an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected behavior, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#55189](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/55189#issuecomment-1656305849).  The [`satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#46827](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/46827), provides a [contextual type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) which can sometimes alter the behavior of type inference.  The reason why this is specific to `boolean` as opposed to, say, `string`, is that `boolean` is really just a shorthand for the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `true | false`. Even though it displays as a single type, it's actually a union.  You can verify this by manually defining a type to be `true | false` and see that it displays as `boolean`:

```
type B = true | false;
//   ^? type B = boolean
```

So `true` when evaluated contextually by `true | false` is kept as `true`, as opposed to `"a"` when evaluated contextually by `string` in a `satisfies` expression, is still widened to `string` as usual.

That's as close as I can get to an "official" answer, anyway, given the details of microsoft/TypeScript#55189. It is unfortunate that the pull request in microsoft/TypeScript#46827 does not go into any detail in its description about how exactly it's supposed to work. There are other parts of TypeScript where providing a `string`/`number` context for a literal will result in a literal type, and that's not happening here, except for `boolean`.  The `boolean` type differs from the others by virtue of it being an explicit union, so it's not too surprising that its behavior would differ, but whether or not this is truly intentional as opposed to just an implementation artifact is impossible for me to say with any certainty.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQlC8VgCcCu0A+UBmBDANgM4QDcAsAFAD0VUdAegPyWVA)